# wpf datagrid identify cursor position on blank row on deleting row

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, cursor

I have a datagrid, with binding to observable collection, that allows the operator to insert a new row or to delete an exiting row by means of "canc" key.

Based on other post of this community, the delete operation has been implemented in this way:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="DiameterGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding} AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True"  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" PreviewKeyDown="RollGrid_PreviewKeyDown">
```

And code behind:

```
...
DiameterGrid.ItemsSource = offer.diameters
...

Private Sub RollGrid_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)

Dim myGrid As DataGrid = CType(e.Source, DataGrid)
Dim myRec As Diameter
    If e.Key = Key.Delete Then
        If myGrid.CurrentItem Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("Invalid record")
        Else
            myRec = CType(myGrid.CurrentItem, Diameter)
            offer.diameters.Remove(myRec)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The delete operation works properly, the problem is that when the cursor is positioned on the blank new row, I have the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in observable collection.exe

The error is raised on the cast operation myRec = CType(myGrid.CurrentItem, Diameter).

I tried to detect the position of the cursor on the blank row with the check:

myGrid.CurrentItem Is Nothing

and in many other different ways, but I couldn't find a solution.

Any suggestion? Answers in C# would also ok...

Thank you in advance for your help